# select mysql COUNT value in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, count

Mysql query looks like this

```
const numOfReplies = await SQL('SELECT COUNT(conversation_id), conversation_id FROM tweet_replies GROUP BY conversation_id')
```

so there are multiple rows with the same conversation_id, and i want to get a number of rows for every conversation_id.
After looping with forEach

```
numOfReplies.forEach(num => {
  console.log(num)
})
```

response looks like this

```
{
  'COUNT(conversation_id)': '10',
  conversation_id: '1530169643423367169'
}
{
  'COUNT(conversation_id)': '10',
  conversation_id: '1530172022357106690'
}
```

how can i select value of COUNT(conversation_id) from this response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply name the COUNT value in SQL request with `AS` keyword and get it like a field :

```
SELECT COUNT(conversation_id) AS myCount, conversation_id FROM tweet_replies GROUP BY conversation_id
```

You will get response like this:

```
{
  myCount: '10',
  conversation_id: '1530169643423367169'
}
{
  myCount: '10',
  conversation_id: '1530172022357106690'
}
```